# how to show selected row of a gridview in datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm getting the values of row of `GridView` but after binding data to `DataList` . `DataList` is not getting visible

aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID ="gvresults" runat="server" 
       onselectedindexchanged="gvresults_SelectedIndexChanged">
   <Columns>
       <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:DataList ID ="dlresults" runat="server"></asp:DataList>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void gvresults_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Keywordid = gvresults.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    string val1 = gvresults.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Tbl_keywords where KeywordID ='" + Keywordid + "'",con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    dlresults.DataSource = ds;
    dlresults.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code and check your `da` has data?

Comment: i debugged and i saw that in  dataset there is having one record@SonerGönül

Answer (score 0):

You shold write it like that:

```
dlresults.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];   
dlresults.DataBind();
dlresults.DataKeyField = "SomeKey";
dlresults.Visible = true;
```

In Your asp code:

```
<asp:DataList ID ="dlresults" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat='server' ID='lblItemName' Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "someVal") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: i tried that 3 lines still not visible datalist, any more idea??@israel altar

Comment: its just printing only one label data. how to print all values . should i take item templates .

Comment: @krishna mohan i don't understand the question, there is an item template in the answer, what do you mean please?

Comment: why we are writting item templates , cant we generate autogeneratad coloumns ?@israel

Comment: No, you need to give the template for it to know how to display the data. So in the data template you give the row template and use Eval.